# alpha fading animation works only once , when bottom up animation of another view finishes in Android

Tags: android

I’m using bottom to top animation for a stone image. I want the animation to start with a delay of 2 seconds and it should finish in 1.5 seconds.
Along with that , I want to show a dust blowing image that goes from alpha = 0 to alpha = 1 in 2 seconds.  I have used AnimationUtil.loadAnimation().

When stone animation is finish, I want the dust image to go from alpha 1 to alpha 0 in 2 seconds. I’m doing that in onAnimationEnd() method. First time all runs well. But 2nd time, Dust image goes off immediately. No alpha animation is there.

Source code is attached:

```
private void showAnimation(Context context){
  final FrameLayout stone = (FrameLayout) (view.findViewById(R.id.Stone));
  stone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  final FrameLayout dust = (FrameLayout) (view.findViewById(R.id.img_Dust));
  dust.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  dust.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1500);



  final Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.stone_up);

  slideUp.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        stone.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        dust.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
              super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                 dust.setVisibility(View.GONE);

           }
        });
     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

     }
  });
  stone.setAnimation(slideUp);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put below lines in onAnimationEnd(Animation animation).

```
if(stone.getVisibility() ==  View.GONE) {
   dust.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Hope, it will work.